# grouping by month and Filtering by quarter

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I have a column named Date Opened, its a date field. Its dtype is datetime64[ns]. What I am trying to do is run through all the dates in my dataframe in the Date Opened column and then somehow create a new column with specific dates. My dates format looks like this:

```
'2012-05-16'
```

I was wondering if there is any way to run through the dates and only bring me back dates that are in the months of jan, feb, mar, and then apr, may, jun and then jul, aug, sep, and finally oct, nov, dec, put them into a separate column that I can filter on by quarter so for jan, feb, mar, that would be Q1 and then the next set of three would be Q2 and so on, and the years aren't all the same so that's why I want to group and filter by quarter.

```
'2012-01-03', '2013-02-03', '2012-03-12'
'2012-01-10', '2013-02-07', '2012-03-13'
'2012-01-13', '2013-02-15', '2012-03-18'
'2012-01-16', '2013-02-19', '2012-03-20'
'2012-01-22', '2013-02-20', '2012-03-21'
'2012-01-23', '2013-02-21', '2012-03-25'
'2012-01-28', '2013-02-28', '2012-03-27'
```

I have tried using datetime and group them but I can't seem to get them in their own column and I don't want the dates to be reliant on year, I want to just pull the dates in by month (quarter) so, no matter what year it is, they still just bring them in according to the quarter that they fall under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an additional column with the numeric quarter of each date with the [`quarter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.quarter.html) attribute and then filter based on that.

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date Opened': s, 'foo': ['test', 'bar']})

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
  Date Opened   foo
0  2016-12-14  test
1  2014-03-12   bar

In [19]: df['quarter'] = df['Date Opened'].dt.quarter

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
  Date Opened   foo  quarter
0  2016-12-14  test        4
1  2014-03-12   bar        1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you! I did not know that it was as simple.